# How to View Long Term Utilization Trends (Graphs) in the DCOS Dashboard

Tags: performance, monitoring, mesos, mesosphere, dcos

I need to view long term utilization trends for DC/OS and be able to drill down (a la graphana/graphite) in my DC/OS dashboard, but I can't seem to find such a feature there.

Is this available in the DCOS dashboard, in DC/OS , or if neither via some third party plugin?

Answer (score 2):

DC/OS metrics, and debugging will be coming out with the release of DC/OS 1.9, which is expected to be GA on 1/26/2017 (not that long from now).

Take a look at [this blog](https://mesosphere.com/blog/2016/10/12/day-2-operations-metrics/) which describes how metrics will work. There's another one for logging

If you have have more questions about metrics and logging you can email jeff@mesosphere.com or hop into the [community slack](http://chat.dcos.io/?_ga=1.95293532.1790439002.1478539864) #day2ops